# Access an excel spreadsheet from word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the following code in word VBA 2010

```
Dim oExcel As excel.Application
Dim oWB As workbook
Set oExcel = New excel.Application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\users\jane\desktop\excelSheet.xlsx")
oExcel.Visible = True 
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open()
```

it has throws a user defined type during the first line - basically, the code has no idea what an excel.Application is; but it knows what an Application is. How to make it know what an excel.Application is? Also, assuming it knows what an excel.Application is, would this code open excelSheet.xlsx at the given location?

Comment: Adding the reference to excel should fix that error. You can also use `CreateObject()` which means you don't need to add the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VBA Editor go to Tools > References and check the Reference to Excel.

Here is a picture (check the line in blue):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference the Excel Vba Library to you Document. Below you see the Vba Editor Window from within a Word Document. You have to click on the menue point *Extras* and then on *References* (I am using a german version of Word so I am assumig that these points are named like that). Then you have to refrence the library you see in the picture (the version is not important, just pick whichever latest version is available to you).

[image: hi]
When you did refrence it you should that lines like `Dim oExcel As excel.Application` change to `Dim oExcel As Excel.Application`, indicating that your VBA environment now knows what `Excel. ...` is. Please note that there are two ways to reference in VBA: early binding and late binding. When you reference as I described you use early binding, which is good for development but bad for everything else. To learn how to you late binding instead a first start would be [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/0tcf61s1.aspx).

**Edit:**
Oh someone answered faster. I will let this answer live though, so you can check the binding part.